# @Named and @Inject is not working to inject bean of service

Tags: spring-mvc, javabeans, spring-annotations, inject, named

I have used to @Named and @Inject several time at office project which works good. I have a personal project where I am implementing in the same way that I had implemented at office work, I am getting  below error while deploying the code in tomcat. Did I miss something here? I have used the inject dependency in POM

> "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException". No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.howtodoinjava.service.TicketService]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@javax.inject.Inject()}

following is the code:

```
@Named
public class TicketServiceImpl implements TicketService{
//do some work here
}

@RestController  
public class TicketController {      
    @Inject     
    private TicketService ticketService; 
    //call service method and dosomething 
}
```

Comment: make sure you have set component scan in your configuration class.

Comment: I have used the component scan as <context:component-scan base-package="com.howtodoinjava.demo" />. Now I found the issue, the service was on different package than what component is scanned. [SOLVED]

Comment: Thats what i was asking you to check.

Comment: @user8838 I have faced the issue that exactly what you faced. I have added <context:component-scan base-package="com.appt.services, com.trial.service" />. But still I am getting the same exception. Can you help me to fix this issue?